# How to insert children of one xml node in another xml node with python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have follwing xml file:

```
<root>
 <nodeA>
  <childrens_A>
 </nodeA>
 <nodeB>
  <childrens_B>
 </nodeB>
 <nodeA>
  <childrens_A>
 </nodeA>
 <nodeB>
  <childrens_B>
 </nodeB>
</root>
```

I want get something like

```
<root>
 <nodeA>
  <childrens_A>
  <childrens_B>
 </nodeA>
 <nodeA>
  <childrens_A>
  <childrens_B>
 </nodeA>
</root>
```

Numbers of nodes A and B equal.
I can import only from standard python library. I cannot import `lxml` because access restriction. So i want be limited `from xml.etree import ElementTree as et`

My code is:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(path_in)
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.gethcildren()
  if child.tag == "nodeA"
     #insert children of nodeB in nodeA

tr.write(path_out)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your desired results, Did you mean `<childrens_A>` tags under nodeA and `<childrens_B>` tags under nodeB? Right now you are rearranging children under different parents.

Comment: In my expected result <childrens_A> and <childrens_B> under nodeB. So I want insert children of nodeB in nodeA and then remove empty nodeB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i find solution:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tr = et.parse(path_in)
    root = tr.getroot()
    for child in root.getchildren():
        if child.tag == 'nodeB':
            sub = child.getchildren()
            i = root.getchildren().index(child)
            root.getchildren()[i - 1].extend(sub)
tr.write(path_out)
```

Hope once this answer can  help to somebody.

Comment: But this checks only for *nodeB*, not potentially other nodes.

Comment: I have only nodeB so for me this is the answer.
For multiple nodes code will be little bit more complex